# can one use script commands in systemd Environment field?

Tags: systemd, environment-variables

I've got a docker-compose file that I use to start up several containers for my service. One of these containers requires an environmental variable to be set (the public ip of the server, to be exact). The OS is a freshly installed Ubuntu 15.10 Server vm.

I'm trying to work out a way to provide this with systemd. The best I've come up with so far is this:

```
[Unit]
Description=service for my product
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
Environment=MY_MASTER_IP=`/sbin/ip addr | grep 'state UP' -A2 | tail -n1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -f1  -d'/'`
Environment=MY_NETWORK_NAME="mynetwork"

Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f /app/master/docker-compose.yml up
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f /app/master/docker-compose.yml stop

[Install]
WantedBy=local.target
```

However, when I use `systemd-analyze verify myapp.service` systemd responds by telling me the line with the crazy shell command is invalid and will be ignored.

```
[/lib/systemd/system/myapp.service:8] Invalid environment assignment, ignoring: MY_MASTER_IP=`/sbin/ip addr | grep 'state UP' -A2 | tail -n1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -f1  -d'/')`
```

I also tried putting the variable assignment directly berfore the docker-compose command (`MY_MASTER_IP=blah blah blah /docker-compose yadda yadda`) like I was able to do with upstart, but systemd liked this even less.

So can the environment line be used like this and if not, what would be the best/most elegant/easiest way to handle this?

Comment: Answerers might like to read where this has been asked before:  http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2014-March/017870.html  http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2014-October/023706.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, As systemd units are not shell scripts nor there is command substitution support. this is an intentional design decision.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up creating a script that gets called in an ExecStartPre statement that writes all the files to an EnvironmentFile. This seemed to be the most effective and easiest way to handle it.